# Connect two bluetooth headphones for audio sharing (Music, and Movies)

Tags: macos, audio, bluetooth, headphones

I am trying to connect two Bluetooth headphones to a MacbookPro. The main purpose is to stream audio in two devices simultaneously. Is there a MacOS feature that would allow me to do this?

Also, I am not considering a Bluetooth splitter, for sound quality purposes.

Edit: Upon further researching, I found this link on Bose forum (https://community.bose.com/t5/Headphones-Archive/Share-Audio-from-MacOS-Macbook-Pro-with-two-or-more-Bluetooth/td-p/46007). Looks like, creating multi-output device may be a solution? (at this moment I am not able to test this, since I do not have more than one Bluetooth headphones). Has anyone tried it this way? Does it work?

Answer (score 81):

Yes, you can do it: https://community.bose.com/t5/Headphones-Archive/Share-Audio-from-MacOS-Macbook-Pro-with-two-or-more-Bluetooth/td-p/46007

Here are the steps I took:

1. Connect both headphones via bluetooth. Both should say connected on the Bluetooth setting page.
2. In Finder menu hit Go -> Utilities -> Audio Midi Setup
3. You should see both your headphones listed on the left here.
4. Hit the "+" button at the bottom left and select "Create Multi-Output Device" (You may rename the device if you wish)
5. Select your bose headphones from the list on the right to add to the Multi-Output Device.
6. Right-click on the Multi-Output Device you just created and use device for sound output and play alerts and sound through this device.
7. You may also select which device as your master device to sync across all your connected headphones.
8. I also selected Drift Correction for slave devices - I'm not 100% sure what this does but I think it makes sure that your devices stay in sync to the audio/video playing on your computer.
9. Watch away. Note that you won't be able to adjust ouput volume from Macbook any more, instead volume is adjusted individually at each headphone, which is pretty neat.

Comment: I have tried user3063895's solution and indeed it works! Thank you SO MIUCH, @user3063895! My wife (and I) will be VERY HAPPY when we fly to Hawaii in a few days and we both can use our BT headphones to watch a movie together!

Comment: I ❤️this answer. You made my romantic evening when the baby sleeps!

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm. Here are the same steps with images: https://www.macrumors.com/how-to/output-mac-audio-two-pairs-headphones/

Comment: This is just brilliant.

Comment: I tried to enable drift for either master, slave or both, but none will keep the devices in sync for me, how can I adjust the delay manually?

Comment: This helped me to fix blutooth earbuds problem, which would not pair with each other on their own.